# Incorrect transformation using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

I am trying to convert point data from EPSG:3080 to EPSG:4326 in PostGIS. When using ST_Transform(geom,4326) against a source column defined as 3080 I am getting incorrect results.  If I use ST_Transform(geom,'proj4_text',4326) (where the proj4 specification for EPSG:3080 is directly from http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3080/) it is giving proper answers.  I looked at the definition for EPSG:3080 in the spatial_ref_sys table and it seems correct, although it is in WKT format rather than proj4).  Clearly I'm misunderstanding or misusing something, but I'm unsure what that might be.

---

Problem was that I entered a (wrong) value and read it as being correct - at least a dozen times.

ST_Transform works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is also field named proj4text in PostGIS. This query

```
select proj4text from spatial_ref_sys where srid=3080;
```

gives me this

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=27.41666666666667 +lat_2=34.91666666666666 +lat_0=31.16666666666667 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=914400 +y_0=914400 +datum=NAD27 +units=ft +no_defs
```

while your link shows another string

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=27.41666666666667 +lat_2=34.91666666666666 +lat_0=31.16666666666667 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=914400 +y_0=914400 +ellps=clrk66 +datum=NAD27 +to_meter=0.3048 +no_defs
```

I can't say which one is correct and on what basis.

Comment: Another reason why spatialreference.org is out of date, while http://epsg.io/3080 is the same as PostGIS, and presumably correct.